# how to run code when rollup watcher fires

Tags: javascript, rollup, rollupjs

Anyone know how to run code whenever the rollup watcher fires? I saw some references to trapping watcher events, like 'start', but I'm using a rollup.config.js file and I have no idea where and how I'd check for such events. FYI, I'm learning service workers and I want to modify the service worker file (appending a '\n' would be sufficient) whenever any of my source code changes.

Answer (score 1):

On a separate forum, I received the following answer. It sounds correct to me, but I haven't implemented it yet so take it for what it's worth:

if you have your npm run dev command run node some-script.js and have some-script.js do something similar to https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#rollupwatch then you can do a watcher.on('event' call and re-run w/e it is you want to run.
you can use your existing config, and import it into some-script.js to pass as options to rollup.watch, with the addition of any watch specific options you'd like to add.

Answer (score 1):

In many cases, the best way to do this is by writing a rollup plugin. Plugins have a `watchChange` callback that you can use to something when changes are detected. If you only want to do it when certain files change, you could use the [minimatch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/minimatch) library to check if the changed file matches a glob you pass in or configure somewhere.

This is a sketch of the solution I came up with:

```js
function demoWatcherPlugin(globs) {
    let doTheAction = false

    return {
        watchChange(id) {
            // Does the file that just changed match one of the globs passed into
            // this plugin?
            const relPath = path.relative(__dirname, id)
            if (
                globs.some(
                    (item) => minimatch.match([relPath], item).length > 0
                )
            ) {
                doTheAction = true
            }
        },

        async buildEnd() {
            if (doTheAction) {
                // Do the action you want to perform when certain files change
            }
        },
    }
}
```

Usage (in `rollup.config.js`):

```js
    plugins: [
        demoWatcherPlugin(['src/foo/**/*.js']),
```